# MLP learning produces bad outcomes for simple cases

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am a newbie in sklearn so I just use some very simple cases to test whether I used the tools correctly.

```
from sklearn import neural_network as nn
from numpy.random import random as random

X = [[int(10*random()), int(10*random())] for i in range(100)]
y = [sum(X[i]) for i in range(100)]

mlp = nn.MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(1))
mlp.fit(X,y)
```

This is just a very simple data set that input elements sum up to be the output.

But when I predict other inputs, the results are completely wrong.
For example:

```
print(mlp.predict([[1,2]]))
[1.14837125]
```

But I am expecting [3] as the ouput (sum of 1 and 2)

`mlp.coefs_` returns `[array([[-0.27704864], [-1.05561447]]), array([[-0.81486066]])]`
I have two entries, so I think there should be three coefficients (two with the entries and one for a constant). What are they? The documents don't state that.

May I know if I misunderstand anything about this function?

Comment: Please show the expected output vs real output.

Comment: For example, I expect mlp.predict([[1,2]]) to give 3, but it gives 1.14837125.

Comment: Ok, still very unclear. `mlp.intercept_` will give you the value needed. And for the second array from the docs `coefs_ : list, length n_layers - 1
The ith element in the list represents the weight matrix corresponding to layer i.`

Comment: I am sorry that I don't quite get what your question is. I am thinking that the relationship between the input and the output is very simple. I am not sure why the mlp is not giving the correct predictions.

Comment: `mlp = nn.MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(1), activation = 'identity') ` Try this. You are unnecessarily brining non-linearity. Plus you don't need an MLP for such a simple task, simple linear regression would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just might not have enough examples (100 is not a big dataset even for such a simple NN). Here is a solution (with some refactoring) that works for me:

```
from sklearn import neural_network as nn
from numpy.random import random

X = random((10000, 2)) * 10
y = X.sum(axis=1)

mlp = nn.MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(1), max_iter=10000, activation='identity')
mlp.fit(X, y)
```

And

```
>>> mlp.predict([(1, 2)])
array([3.01464952])
```

And with 100'000 examples and 100'000 iterations:

```
>>> mlp.predict([(1, 2)])
array([3.00000032])
```